# Reiniciar bucle for en python

Tags: python, bucle-for, binance

Alguien sabe cómo reiniciar este bucle for cuando se cumpla la condición de que la variable diferencia sea mayor que 0.25? Necesito que la variable contador se almacene y no se reinicie cada vez que se cumpla la condición. Estaba intentando hacerlo con ***continue*** pero con esto la variable ***first_price*** no se reinicia.

```
minutos_dia = 2880
first_price = 0
contador = 0
diferencia = 0
contador = 0


for i in range(1,minutos_dia):

    time.sleep(3)

    btc = client.get_symbol_ticker(symbol="ADAUSDT", )
    btc_price = float(btc["price"])
    print( '                            '               )
    print('the actual value for ADA is:',btc_price)

    if i == 1:
        first_price = btc_price
        print('the first price is:',first_price)
    
    diferencia = ((btc_price-first_price)/first_price)*100
    print('the % difference is:',diferencia)
    
    if (diferencia > 0.25): 
        contador = contador + 1
        continue
    print('Contador:',contador)
```

Comment: quieres guardar el valor de `contador` o de `first_price`?

Comment: ¿Qué se almacene dónde? Además, no sé bien a que le llamas reiniciar... en el código la variable se inicializa una única vez y luego se va incrementando cuando se cumple la condición, por lo que yo diría que no se _reinicia_ nunca. Obviamente diferimos en lo que entendemos por _reiniciar_ que, para mi, sería volver a 0.

Comment: Lo que quiero es  volver a iniciar el ***for*** desde el comienzo cuando se cumpla la condición de que la diferencia sea mayor que 0.25

Comment: Es decir, que todo inicie nuevamente

Comment: Hasta que se vuelva a cumplir la condición

Comment: Y que la variable ***contador*** sea quien lleve el conteo de las veces que la condición se cumplió

Comment: Tengo una respuesta a tu duda, pero la cuestión está en que primero necesito un poco de información. Que variables quieres reiniciar? Hasta cuando el for se debe reiniciar? Debe reiniciarse hasta que el contador llegue a x? Si el bucle for termina y la diferencia NO es mayor a 0.25, quieres que se reinicie igualmente?

Comment: ¿Qué variables necesitas reiniciar? Cuando dices "que se reinicie todo", te refieres realmente a todas las variables? En ese caso la siguiente repetición del bucle sería de nuevo idéntica a la primera, por lo que la condición se cumpliría de nuevo en el mismo lugar, y si lo vuelves a reiniciar todo en ese momento vuelves a estar como al principio, así una y otra vez ¿cuándo terminaría el programa?

Answer (score 0):

Tu código esta mal, pues la diferencia siempre es 0, esto por estas líneas de código

```py
    if i == 1:
        first_price = btc_price #ambas tiene el mismo valor
        print('the first price is:',first_price)
    
    # el valor se resta asi mismo da 0 y toda operacion (* o /) da 0
    diferencia = ((btc_price-first_price)/first_price)*100
```

Supongamos que `btc_price` es 2 vamos a ver que pasa

```py
    btc_price = float(2)
    if i == 1:
        first_price = btc_price #ambos tienen el valor de 2
        print('the first price is:',first_price)
    
    diferencia = ((btc_price-first_price)/first_price)*100
    #operamos manualmente
    """
    diferencia = ((2-2)/2)*100
    diferencia = (0/2)*100
    diferencia = 0 * 100
    diferencia = 0
    """
```

Esto provoca que nunca se cumpla tu condición `if (diferencia > 0.25)`

Para probar tu codigo reemplace el valor de `btc` y añadi un `print()` para ver los valores

**Ojo**
Tienes que tener cuidado con el `continue` ya que esto hará que el ciclo vuelva al inicio, por lo que omite lo que esta después, esto provocara que las veces que se cumpla la condición esta no imprima el valor. De aquí en adelante será omitida, esto para tener el correcto resultado.

```py
for i in range(1,minutos_dia):

    time.sleep(3)

    btc = {"price":2}
    btc_price = float(btc["price"])
    print( '                            '               )
    print('the actual value for ADA is:',btc_price)

    if i == 1:
        first_price = btc_price
        print('the first price is:',first_price)
    print(f'\nlos valores son \nbtc_price={btc_price}\nfirst_price={first_price}\n')
    diferencia = ((btc_price-first_price)/first_price)*100
    print('the % difference is:',diferencia)
    
    if (diferencia > 0.25): 
        contador = contador + 1
        #continue -> esto omite lo que esta después y vuelve al inicio del ciclo
    print('Contador:',contador)
```

**Salida**

```py
the actual value for ADA is: 2.0
the first price is: 2.0

los valores son 
btc_price=2.0
first_price=2.0

the % difference is: 0.0
Contador: 0
                            
the actual value for ADA is: 2.0

los valores son 
btc_price=2.0
first_price=2.0

the % difference is: 0.0
Contador: 0
...
#sigue hasta que acaba el ciclo
```

Tu pregunta es muy confusa, no se si quieres mantener el valor de `contador` o de `first_price` pero te digo en caso quieras mantener el valor de `first_price` pues deberas declarar la variable `btc_price` fuera del ciclo e ir incrementando al igual que haces con el contador, y si lo que quieres es mantener e incrementar el valor de `contador` ya lo estas haciendo, la cosa es que nunca se cumple tu condicion por las razones antes mencionadas

Hice un ejemplo para demostrar que esta variable si se mantiene e incrementa.

**Ejemplo**

```py
import random

minutos_dia = 2880
contador = 0

for i in range(1,minutos_dia):
    btc = round(random.random(),3)
    btc_price = 1

    diferencia = btc_price-btc

    if (diferencia > 0.25): 
        contador += 1
        #continue -> esto omite lo que esta después y vuelve al inicio del ciclo 
    print('Contador:',contador)
```

**Salida**

```
Contador: 1
Contador: 2
Contador: 2 #se imprime dos veces ya que el print() esta fuera de la condición
Contador: 3
Contador: 4
Contador: 5
Contador: 6
Contador: 7
Contador: 8
... #sigue imprimiendo hasta que acabe el ciclo
```

Answer (score 0):

Pues creo que para reiniciar denuevo first_price debes cambiarla antes del continue

```py
minutos_dia = 2880
first_price = 0
contador = 0
diferencia = 0
contador = 0
for i in range(1,minutos_dia):
    time.sleep(3)
    btc = client.get_symbol_ticker(symbol="ADAUSDT", )
    btc_price = float(btc["price"])
    print(' ')
    print('the actual value for ADA is:',btc_price)
    if i == 1:
        first_price = btc_price
        print('the first price is:',first_price)
    diferencia = ((btc_price-first_price)/first_price)*100
    print('the % difference is:',diferencia)
    
    if (diferencia > 0.25): 
        contador += 1
        first_price=0
        continue
    print('Contador:',contador)
```

tomando en cuenta que a reiniciar te refieres a volver first_price a su valor inicial, otra manera de hacerlo es estableciendo first_price a btc_price